# not able to create a web driver instance in python

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to create a web driver instance in the python with the following code:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
import Selenium2Library
from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library

def get_webdriver_instance():
    s2l = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("Selenium2Library")
    return s2l._current_browser()
```

but at BuiltIn().get_library_instance("Selenium2Library") I am getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py", line 2922, in get_library_instance
        return self._namespace.get_library_instance(name)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py", line 70, in _namespace
        return self._context.namespace
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py", line 65, in _context
        raise RobotNotRunningError('Cannot access execution context')
robot.libraries.BuiltIn.RobotNotRunningError: Cannot access execution context
```

Could someone please help me in resolving this error

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you can't use methods of the BuiltIn library unless you are actually running a test (via pybot, jybot, etc). You can't call `BuiltIn().get_library_instance('Selenium2Library')` in a standalone python script.

Comment: I am running the test using pybot command but still i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

`_current_browser` is only return the current browser

If you want to use Selenium2Library in python than you can do the next

```
from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library
sl = Selenium2Library()
sl.open_browser('firefox')
```